# How to index table for different single-column clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
  device varchar(12),
  pin varchar(4),
  authToken varchar(32),
  Primary Key (device)
);
```

At different points of the application I need to query this table by different *single* column clause. Meaning I have the following queries:

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE device = ?;
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE authToken = ?;
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE pin = ?;
```

As I understand it, in this scenario a combined index of `(device, authToken, pin)` makes no sense, because that would only speed up the first query, not the second or third.

Reading speed is more important than writing for this table, so would simply indexing each column individually be the optimal solution here?

Comment: Yep, you need three separate single-column indexes. Well, the first one (`device`) is already included in the primary key, so you only need two extra ones.

Comment: How important is "reading" as opposed to writing? Because you can even go as far as to implement covering indexes, if you wish your queries to be blazing fast. That is, by using secondary indexes and avoiding the primary one. I assume your tables are InnoDB tables, am I right?

Comment: @TheImpaler yes, InnoDB will be used. A "covering Index" would be a combined index for all columns or an individual one for each?

Comment: A covering index includes all the columns the query references. Therefore it's not a single-column index; it starts with the "filtering columns" (columns in the WHERE) and then includes the rest: in short, it's extremely fast for select, but it's expensive to insert/delete/update. Furthermore, you have three queries, each one requiring a separate covering index; that is, this solution will make your selects very fast at the expense of the modification operations. Use it only if you need high select speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward answer is to create separate single-column indexes for each query:

```
create index ix1 (device); -- no need to create it since it's the PK.
create index ix2 (pin);
create index ix3 (authToken);
```

The first index (from the PK) uses the primary index. The second and third ones could be slower since they suffer from the "secondary index" slowness: they always need to access the secondary index first, then access the primary index; this could becomes slow if you are selecting a high number of rows.

Now, if you want to go overboard in terms of `SELECT` speed at the expense of slowness on modifications (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE`), you can use "covering indexes" tailored to each query. These should look like:

```
create index ix4 (device, pin, authToken); -- [non needed] optimal for WHERE device = ?
create index ix5 (authToken, device, pin); -- optimal for WHERE authToken = ?
create index ix6 (pin, device, authToken); -- optimal for WHERE pin = ?
```

**Note**: As indicated by Rick James `ix4` is redundant with the primary key index InnoDB tables have. There's no need to create it. It's listed here only for completeness.

These "covering indexes" only use the secondary indexes, resolving the query without the need of accessing the primary index at all. They are much faster for high number of rows retrieved.

Comment: Don't add `ix4`; it is totally redundant with the PK.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to index pin column as it's already indexed. For other 2 columns (i.e. device and authToken), yes as per your shared queries, it's better to keep them both indexed individually.

Please note that you will see a big performance improvement when you have high number of such queries hitting the server where you also have huge dataset on this table.

Comment: Is there any performance drawback to these individual indexes? Will this be noticeably slower on very small datasets?

Comment: Not at all. You put the indexes and I'm sure you are gonna love the performance :-)

Answer (score 0):

To answer:

> *"How to index table for different single-column clauses?"*

```
CREATE INDEX Test_device_index ON Test(device);
CREATE INDEX Test_authToken_index ON Test(authToken DESC);
CREATE INDEX Test_pin_index ON Test(pin);
```

Comment: Why the `DESC` on the `authToken`-table? Also, this is basically creating an index for each column individually, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @LukasKnuth I used `DESC` only for the sake of example, no particular reason other than making a learner exposed to it. As far as I know, yes it is individually creating an index for each column.

Comment: `DESC` is ignored in `CREATE INDEX` (until MySQL 8.0).

Comment: The `PRIMARY KEY` is an index; so don't add another index for `device`.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the schema I'd suggest:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  device VARCHAR(255),
  pin VARCHAR(255),
  authToken VARCHAR(255),
  UNIQUE KEY index_authToken (authToken),
  UNIQUE KEY index_device (device),
  KEY index_pin (pin)
);
```

Where you have an `id` type column that's not associated with any particular data, and you have `UNIQUE` constraints on `authToken` and `device`.

Remember to have any column used in a `WHERE` indexed and test your coverage with things like:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ... FROM Test WHERE pin=?
```

If you see "table scan" in the plan then that's a problem of missing indexes.

It's also a good idea to use `VARCHAR(255)` as a default unless you have a very compelling reason to restrict it. Enforce length restrictions in your application layer where they can easily be relaxed later. For example, changing to 6-digit PIN vs. 4 is a simple code change and can even be rolled out incrementally, it's not a schema alteration.

Comment: I don't think the columns `pin` and `authToken` are unique. Are they?

Comment: @TheImpaler It's a wild guess here but I'd hope that an authentication token is unique or else what device is it authenticating?

Comment: No.  You now have 3 unique keys; this slows down inserts.  Using a surrogate `id` slows down the lookup by `device`.  `VARCHAR(255)` -- Yes, have a conservative limit, but an unreasonably big limit is inefficient in certain situations.

Comment: @RickJames Unless this table has over a hundred million entries and has an aggressive level of writes, the cost of an extra index is inconsequential. Additionally, due to the way MySQL uses the `PRIMARY KEY` value as a row identifier in all indexes, large primary keys can have a huge impact on performance. Other databases like Postgres always have an internal row identifier used in indexes to avoid this penalty. MySQL does not.

Comment: @tadman - By avoiding the row identifier, MySQL can fetch (via the PK) the row directly.  This makes the "penalty" actually a performance benefit (for the PK).  In this situation, I do not consider a 12-char PK to be large enough to have a "huge" impact.

Comment: @RickJames Both approaches are valid under different circumstances.